# Gradle Failiure: Could not determine java version from '13.0.1'

Tags: java, gradle

iam trying to build the MAS project-ubin (https://github.com/project-ubin/ubin-corda)  PoC but it seems to be failing on the first step:

```
./gradlew clean build deployNodes`
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '13.0.1'.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I have tried reinstalling both
 java and upgrading gradle but to no avail.

Comment: Upgrade gradle.

Comment: I have with `brew upgrade gradle`

Comment: ```
brew upgrade gradleUpdating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 3 taps (homebrew/cask-versions, homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
ccache                 libxlsxwriter          mlt

Error: gradle 6.0.1 already installed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gradle wrapper script (the 'w' in `gradlew`) will download the version of Gradle that has been specified for that particular project. You don't have to install or download anything manually. The idea is that you will automatically get the version of Gradle that has been verified to work with the project.

Check the version that is used in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. For Java 13, you need Gradle 6 or newer. If it is too old and you like to upgrade it, run `gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.0.1 --distribution-type all`.

You can delete your locally installed version of Gradle if you like (or keep it around in case you want to initialize a new project from scratch).